# Find overlapping timestamps using pandas

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe containing start times, end times and transaction_ids like so:

```
    tid       starttime        endtime
0   0.0     1537204247.00   1537204309.00
1   1.0     1537204248.00   1537204309.00
2   21.0    1537207170.00   1537207196.00
```

I need to find *overlapping* transactions. So far, the most optimized code I've been able to produce is the following:

```
p['overlap'] = False # This is my original dataframe

def compute_overlaps(df):
    for i, row_curr in df.iterrows():
        if( p.loc[row_curr['ix']]['overlap'] != True ):
            overlap_indexes = df[(row_curr['ix'] != df['ix']) & (row_curr['starttime'] < df['endtime']) & (df['starttime'] < row_curr['endtime'])].index
            p['overlap'].loc[row_curr['ix']] = True
            p['overlap'].loc[overlap_indexes] = True

<p_grouped_by_something>.apply(compute_overlaps)
```

Output:

```
    tid       starttime        endtime     overlap
0   0.0     1537204247.00   1537204309.00   True
1   1.0     1537204248.00   1537204309.00   True
2   21.0    1537207170.00   1537207196.00   False
```

Note that for each transaction, I merely need to determine if it overlaps with *at most* one other transaction. If one is found, I don't need to check all other transactions; I can stop there and mark it as overlapping.

Initially, I had a nested `for` loop using `iterrows` that was abominably slow. I was then able to vectorize the inner loop, but the outer loop remains. Is there any way to vectorize the overall computation to make it run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `numpy` boradcast

```
s1=df.starttime.values
s2=df.endtime.values
sum(np.minimum(s2[:,None],s2)-np.maximum(s1[:,None],s1)>0)>1
Out[36]: array([ True,  True, False])
```

Explanation :

1st : over lap for range

(x1,y1) with (x2,y2)
min(y2,y1)-max(x1,x2)>0 then two ranges have overlap

2nd : why it need great than 2 , since I using `numpy` braod cast , so the diagonal always represented itself comparison . Then we need greater two .

Update :

Assuming you have df and split df1 ....dfn (look at np.split)

```
s1=df.starttime.values
s2=df.endtime.values
l=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5...]
n=[]
for  x in l: 
       n.append(sum(np.minimum(s2[:,None],x.values)-np.maximum(s1[:,None],x.values)>0)>1)
```

Comment: I ran into a MemoryError when `len(df)` is large. For example, when `len(df) = 172484`, I believe this will create multiple 172484 x 172484 matrices, and much of the computation is unnecessary (because the same elements are compared again and again in every row). What can be done to optimize this?

Comment: @lostsoul29 split your df into small pieces then do this , and concat it back

Comment: Not sure that will work, because I need to compute overlapping transactions taking into account *all* transactions. If I operate on slices, wouldn't the code only determine overlapping transactions for that slice? For example, in the df in the question, if `tid = 1.0` was in a different slice, it wouldn't be compared with `tid = 0.0`, and its `overlap` value might be `False`, thus giving incorrect results.